# Delete vectors from cell array elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array containing double arrays like:

```
x = {[4,1] [4,3] [1,1] [2,3] [2,1]};
```

I would like to check if [1,1] is contained in the cell array and if so, delete it. I get it done like this:

```
x(find(cellfun(@all,cellfun(@(x)x==[1,1],x(:),'UniformOutput', false))==1)) = []
```

Seems overy complicated though, any suggestions for simplification? thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is meant to be a MATLAB question then please tag it as such (and delete the other irrelevant tags at the same time).

Comment: No problem - I've fixed the formatting and tags for you.

Comment: Can't you use a 2-column matrix instead of a cell array? It would be more efficient, and easier to deal with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the same code you used, but removing everything unnecessary. You don't need to apply cellfun twice to apply two nested functions. Pass the nested function instead.

```
x(cellfun(@(x)all(x==[1,1]),x)=[]
```

Besides this, take a look at "logical indexing", you don't need `find` in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `cellfun`, one can use [**`ismember`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to detect the matching rows and remove them  -

```
x(ismember(vertcat(x{:}),[1 1],'rows'))=[]
```